# How do I remove an element from a Vector?

Tags: scala, collections, vector, immutability, trie

This is what I'm doing now:

```
  private var accounts = Vector.empty[Account]

  def removeAccount(account: Account)
  {
    accounts = accounts.filterNot(_ == account)
  }
```

Is there a more readable solution? Ideally, I'd like to write `accounts = accounts.remove(account)`.

Comment: What should happen if the account is present in two (or more) copies ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use this:

```
accounts filterNot account.==
```

Which reads pretty well to me, but ymmv. I'd also like a `count` that doesn't take a predicate, but the collection library is really lacking in specialized methods where one with a predicate can generalize the operation.

Until 2.8.x, there *was* a `-` method, which got deprecated, iirc, because of semantic issues. It could actually have come back on 2.10 if my memory is serving me right, but it didn't. **Edit:** I checked it out, and saw that `-` is now reserved for a *mutable* method that modifies the collection it is applied on. I'd be all in favor of `-:`/`:-` though on sequences, where it makes sense to drop the first or last element equal to something. Anyone willing to front a ticket for that? I'd upvote it. :-)

Answer (score 5):

There unfortunately is not, and worse still (perhaps), if the same account is present twice, `filterNot` will remove both of them.  The only thing I can offer for readability is to use

```
accounts.filter(_ != account)
```

Another possibility is to use a collection type that does have a remove operation, such as a `TreeSet` (where it is called `-`).  If you don't have duplicate entries anyway, a `Set` is perfectly okay.  (It is slower for some operations, of course, but it probably is a better fit to the application--it's more efficient at removing individual entries; with a `filterNot` you basically have to build the entire `Vector` again.)

Comment: Is there an immutable `Set` that organizes the elements in the order they were inserted in?

Comment: There is `scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: `TreeSet` can be ordered but you have to supply your own ordering.  That turns out to be awkward, though: you need to know the index for ordering in order to search for your item.  If it can be a property of the `Account` you're in good shape.  otherwise it's hard to add on, because you need to know e.g. an ID number in order to find your item, but you only have the item not its ID.

Comment: You can use the `diff` method to remove a controlled number of instances

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like this:

```
def removeFirst[T](xs: Vector[T], x: T) = {
  val i = xs.indexOf(x)
  if (i == -1) xs else xs.patch(i, Nil, 1)
}
```

then

```
accounts = removeFirst(accounts, account)
```

I think the nub of the problem, though, is that a `Vector` probably isn't the right collection type for a *set* of items where you want to pull things out (hint: try `Set`). If you want to index on an ID or an insertion index then `Map` could be what you're after (which does have a `-` method). If you want to index on multiple things efficiently, you need a database!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `diff` method which is defined for all sequences. It computes the multiset difference between two sequences - meaning it will remove as many occurrences of an element as you need.

```
Vector(1, 2, 1, 3, 2).diff(Seq(1)) => 
Vector(2, 1, 3, 2)

Vector(1, 2, 1, 3, 2).diff(Seq(1, 1)) =>
Vector(2, 3, 2)

Vector(1, 2, 1, 3, 2).diff(Seq(1, 1, 2))  
Vector(3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer not to use the `filterNot` closure, you could use the more verbose yet more explicit for-comprehension style instead.

```
private var accounts = Vector.empty[Account]

def removeAccount(account: Account)
{
    accounts = for { a <- accounts
                     if a != account } yield { a }
}
```

It's a matter of personal preference whether this is felt to be better in this case.

Certainly for more complex expressions involving nested flatMaps etc, I agree with Martin Odersky's advice that for-comprehensions can be quite a bit easier to read, especially for novices.